# Did Russia and Ukraine exchange Crimea for Taganrog?

Tags: 20th-century, russia, ukraine, crimea

Did Ukraine give Russia the [Taganrog](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Taganrog) region in exchange for Crimea?

Answer (score 11):

No, that's not true.

The Taganrog [Okrug](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Okrug) was administered by the [Ukrainian SSR](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ukrainian_Soviet_Socialist_Republic), but only briefly (1920 - 1924) and it was transferred back to the [Russian SFSR](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Russian_Soviet_Federative_Socialist_Republic) 30 years before [Khrushchev gifted Crimea to the Ukrainian SSR](https://history.stackexchange.com/q/4418/739).

Answer (score 4):

No, that's not true. The Crimea was joined to Ukrainian Soviet Socialist Republic (USSR) for the same economical, culture and agricultural contacts between Crimea and Ukraine under authority of Decree of the presidium of the supreme soviet of the USSR on January 19, 1954.
The Minutes of the meeting of the Central Committee of the CPSU No. 49, January 25, 1954 have not mention about Taganrog or other cities\lands: http://sevkrimrus.narod.ru/texstes/vozvrat.htm#41   So, Crimea was joined to Ukraine without other supplementary conditions.
More importantly - Taganrog was officially founded by Peter the Great on September 12, 1698 as first Russian Navy base near Turkey border. Soviet power was established on December 25, 1919, On December 17, 1920 the city joined the Ukrainian SSR as the administrative center of Taganrog Okrug. However, it was transferred to the Russian SFSR along with Shakhty Okrug on October 1, 1924. 1920-1924 - that's only.
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Taganrog (the russian wiki Таганрог have more historical, economical and geographic details).
Here is a link, find official archival documents (original) of Protocol # 49 http://taganrogcity.com/pr_refutation_false_statement_by_blogger_alexander_gorobets.html - these documents prove that the Russian Federation did not receive anything in exchange.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, that is 100 % True!

> > There is one very important detail that somehow everybody today shamefully keeps silent about.
> > In exchange to Crimea received (Minutes of the Presidium of the CPSU (Communist Party of Soviet Union) Central Committee number 49 from January 25, 1954) Ukraine has given up to Russia Taganrog and its bordering lands the size of Crimea peninsula in the Black Sea.
>
> Есть еще одна очень важная деталь, о которой почему-то все сегодня стыдливо умалчивают. Что взамен Крыма от Украины в Российскую Федерацию тогда же (протокол Президиума ЦК КПСС №49 от 25 января 1954 г.) передали Таганрог и приграничные к нему земли, по территории равные площади полуострова в Черном море.

Full text can be found here:

What Russia had received in return Crimea in 1954

http://uainfo.org/yandex/295891-chto-poluchila-rossiya-vzamen-kryma-v-1954-godu.html
http://narodna.pravda.com.ua/politics/533404aba98e2/

Comment: Please provide some notable references. Otherwise this looks like a personal unsubstantiated opinion of some journalist.